# Google Analytics - Track Certain Page

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a client that is taking out an advert in a newspaper, and they want to track how many visits they get from that advert.

In Google Analytics, how can I track how many visits to a certain page that redirects to the homepage?

So if I go to sitename.co.uk/newspaper/, it will redirect to the homepage and I need to track how many hits to that url.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page redirects to the home page have it redirect with UTM codes so you can filter those pages and see what marketing channel they came from. I've used this with clients who do newspaper and commericals and it works out great.

Here is the Google UTM builder https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

For example:

domain.co.uk/?utm_source=newspaper&utm_medium=advert&utm_campaign=January%20edition

I would make the source = newspaper, the medium = advert, and the campaign = the january edition.

Having the UTM are great for tracking and wont change the site. You can also set a custom variable to cookie that user and be able to see how much traffic and value that newspaper has sent over time.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I want. Where in analytics would I be able to see this data? Sorry I'm not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the page they land on redirects without loading the Google Analytics JavaScript library, you won't be able to catch visits to that page in the first case.

My suggestion would be to append campaign tracking parameters after the redirect has happened.

To clarify, and that I have understood your question, if sitename.co.uk/newspaper/ redirects to sitename.co.uk, then append utm-parameters to that URL.

So, for example, using the [URL builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en), you'd get something like:

```
sitename.co.uk/?utm_campaign=newspaper_ad&utm_medium=advertorial&utm_source=newspaper_name
```

Remember that you always need utm_campaign, source and medium in your utm tracking parameters.